# Не правильно или неправильно? В данном предложении слитно или раздельно употребляется слово "не( )правильно"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

— Правильно ли это?
— Нет, не( )правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более верным будет **слитное** написание, буквально: *Нет, это является неправильным.* Иными словами, в данном случае утверждается неправильность того, о чём речь.

При раздельном написании смысл фразы такой: *Нет, это не является правильным.* Правильность отрицается, получается ответ **в лоб.**